# Fetch new MySQL entries and append to existing div's dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I have a PHP script to selected records for comments from a database, and then print them onto the page. What I'd like to happen is that if a user is on a page, and another user comments on an item on said page, it automatically appends the new comment to the bottom. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to differentiate between all of the statuses.

My code for generating the comments on a status is:

```
<?php 

$rt = ("SELECT * FROM (SELECT comment as comment, byuid as byuid, comuid as comuid, likes as likes, dislikes as dislikes, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) as timestamp FROM mingle_comments WHERE onuid = '$sid' AND type = 'status' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2) mingle_comments ORDER BY timestamp ASC"); //query
$result = mysql_query($rt) or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 2) {
    ?>
    <div id="sa" style="background:#E0E0E0; padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;">
        <a href="#" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#3a3a3a; text-decoration:none;">View all comments...</a>
    </div>
    <?php
}

while($st = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$comment = nl2br($st['comment']);
$by = $st['byuid'];
$comuid = $st['comuid'];
$time = $st['timestamp'];
$l = $st['likes'];
$d = $st['dislikes'];

$bq = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '$by' LIMIT 1";
$bqq = mysql_query($bq) or die (mysql_error());

while($bqr = mysql_fetch_assoc($bqq)) {
    $dp = $bqr['dp'];
    $fbq = $bqr['fname'];
    $sbq = $bqr['sname'];
}
?>

<div id="commentbox" class="<?php echo $comuid; ?>" style="padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;">
    <div id="cbi" style=" display:inline; position:relative; ">
        <img src="<?php if ($dp == null) { echo 'img/unknown_user.jpg'; } else { echo "pf/" . $by . "/" . $dp; } ?>" width="36px" style=" display:inline; position:relative;"/>
    </div>
    <div id="cbt" style="position:relative; margin-left:32px; margin-top:-35px;">
        <a href="profile.php?uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>" style="position:relative; font-size:13px; margin-left:10px; font-family:Arial; color:#3a3a3a; text-decoration:none;"><?php echo $fbq . " " . $sbq; ?></a>
        <p class="<?php echo $comuid; ?>" style="position:relative; margin-left:5px;"><?php echo $comment; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div id="clb" style="background:#E0E0E0; padding-left:5px;">
        <a href="#">Like</a><a href="#" id="time"><?php echo time_since($time); ?></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

TL:DR; How can I automatically fetch new comments and append them to the comments generated in the above script without page refresh.

Comment: You need to use jquery's $.ajax call to bring the new results. It's really simple, If you want I can provide some code for you

Comment: @AviateX14 What you want is a technique commonly referred to as 'long polling'

Comment: @AviateX14 added some code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastcheck='';
    setInterval(function() {


        $.ajax({
            url:    'URL_TO_PHP_SCRIPT', 
            type:   'POST',
            data:   {'lastcheck':lastcheck},
            success: function(result){ 
                if (result!='nothing_new'){
                    lastcheck=result.lastcheck /*Update lastcheck*/
                    var data=result.data;

                    $.each(data, function(i,val){
                        //Foreach comment you do what you need, like append, prepend, etc.  data[i]."key" to get the value.
                    }); 

                }
            }
        });

    }, 15000 /* This will check each 15 seconds, you can change it */);

});
```

**PHP SIDE**

```
        $lastcheck=$_POST['lastcheck'];
        /*

        You should add a date field to each new created comment,then filter by "orderby date > $lastcheck" so you get comments since your last check
        You get the new comments here
        ...
        ...
        ..
        */

        if (!empty($arrayofnewcomments)){
             /*The output*/
            echo json_encode(array('lastcheck'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'data'=>$arrayofnewcomments)); 
        }else{/*No new comments*/
            echo 'nothing_new';
        }
```

This is some code I came up with, it's a general Idea but it works. It will check each 15 seconds for new comments.