# SELECT query only outputting one result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am running into an issue with a `SELECT` query. The query is only outputting one result, instead of all of the rows in this database.

Does anyone see why?

```
$select_comments_sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM home_comments
    ORDER BY id DESC
";
  if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
        //$select_comments_stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
        $select_comments_stmt->execute();
        if (!$select_comments_stmt->errno) {
            //echo "error";
        }
        $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date);

        $comment_array = array();
        while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
            $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
            $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_date;
        }
        if ($home_comments === NULL) {
            echo 'No comments found.';
        } else {
            echo $comment_username. "<br>";
            echo $home_comments. "<br><br><br>";
        }
  }
```

AJAX

```
$("#comment-form").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var home_comment = $("#home_comment").val();

    $.ajax({ 
        url: "ajax-php/comment-send.php", 
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "home_comment": home_comment
        },
        success: function (data) {
        //  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
            if (data == "Error!") {
                alert("Unable to post comment!");
                alert(data);
            } else {
                $("#comment-form")[0].reset();
                //$('.newsletter-popup').fadeIn(350).delay(2000).fadeOut();
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
            console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
$user = new User();

    $home_comment = $_POST['home_comment'];
    $username = $user->data()->username;
    $okay = true;

    if ( $okay ) { 

        $comment_insert = "
            INSERT INTO home_comments 
            (id, user_id, username, comment, date)
            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())
            ";
        $comment_stmt = $con->prepare($comment_insert);
        $comment_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $id, $user_id, $username, $home_comment);
        $comment_stmt->execute();
        }
```

Comment: Please check whether your while loop and the assignment to the array is correct. seems like it is replacing the values and only the last value should be there

Comment: Since you're echoing the result outside the loop, you will only get the last result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting the results outside of the while loop. Since you're storing the entire result set into the `$comment_array[]`, you could dump this as well, to get all the comments fetched from DB or, alternatively, output them inside the loop.

```
if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
    //$select_comments_stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
    $select_comments_stmt->execute();
    if (!$select_comments_stmt->errno) {
        //echo "error";
    }
    $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date);

    $comment_array = array();
    while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
        $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
        $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
        $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
        $comment_array[] = $comment_date;
        if ($home_comments === NULL) {
            echo 'No comments found.';
        } else {
            echo $comment_username. "<br>";
            echo $home_comments. "<br><br><br>";
        }
    }
    // Alternatively: print_r($comment_array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question. This select query is for page load to show comments. However, I have an ajax call that inserts the comments when submitted, could I add this same select query within the ajax, under the insert to make it display the new comment right after submit (without page load) or would I have to do something else?

Comment: It's not a good idea to  run the whole query and get the whole result set again.You can write ajax request to fetch only the new comments.

Comment: @Paul Deferring the content load is a good practice. You should also set a limit on number of comments fetched in a call. I'd also suggest the same thing as Suhail above commented.

Comment: How would I only fetch the new comments? I added my ajax and php file for inserting the comments, I was hoping I could add it to these files, instead of creating two new files.

Comment: @Paul There are several questions for the same: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25819790 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/11229645

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues with the code you've written. First of all you're appending each column's value in `$comment_array` array. You should create a sub array in while loop and that in `$comment_array` to make multi dimensional array.

Secondly You're just displaying the value of `$comment_username` which would be the last username from the while loop.

You should loop over the `$comment_array` and display each username and comments individually.

Code would look something this,

```
    $comment_array = array();
    while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
        $sub_array=array();
        $sub_array["userid"] = $comment_user_id;
        $sub_array["username"] = $comment_username;
        $sub_array["comments"] = $home_comments;
        $sub_array["date"] = $comment_date;
        $comment_array[]=$sub_array;
    }
    if ($home_comments === NULL) {
        echo 'No comments found.';
    } else {
        echo $comment_username. "<br>";
        echo $home_comments. "<br><br><br>";

        // Loop over comments array.

        foreach($comment_array as $comment) {
            echo $comment["username"]. "<br>";
            echo $comment["comments"]. "<br><br><br>";
        }
    }
```